# Sum hours per year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate how many years of service someone has based on hours they worked each year. Hours have to be over 2080 from date of hire to anniversary date each year. Below is how I have setup SQL to find out hours per year, but have to update the date and run for each year. Is there an easier way to do this? Can I have an SQL that sums up how many years someone worked over 2080?

```
SELECT Sum(hours)
FROM hours_txn
WHERE EMPNO = 1824 and Type = 'WRK'
and TransactionDate between '1989-04-15 00:00:00' and '1990-04-15 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` to get hours for each year.

Comment: And use `HAVING SUM(hours) > 2080` to report the years where it was over 2080.

Comment: On the off chance hours_txn has an entry on '1990-04-15 00:00:00 it would be included in two years computation: from 89-90 and 90-91. Also over or equal to & over 2080?  (40*52=2080) seems Like I get shorted years of service unless overtime is put in.

Comment: If you want helpful answers, tag your question correctly. Don't use `mysql` for SQL-Server questions.

Comment: Sorry new to this.. I am using SQL Server

Comment: why not just sum(hours) / 2080? This would mean that partial years, combined, would equal a full year. Or are you only looking for FULL years of service?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove the hardcoded "date of hire", you'll need to implement some way to calculate that.  In the query below, I use a (manually set) variable for illustration of what the rest of your query might look like:

```
begin
    declare @hiredate datetime
    set @hiredate = '1989-04-15'

    select count(*)
    from hours_txn
    where EMPNO = 1824 and Type = 'WRK'
    group by datediff(y, @hiredate, TransactionDate)
    having sum([hours]) > 2080
end
go
```

This `group by` gives you 1 record per year of service, and the `having` filters to "years over 2080 hours", and the `count(*)`, well, it counts :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I get no errors when running but no results. Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend "deconstructing" the query into something simpler for your troubleshooting.  For example, you can `select *, datediff(y, @hiredate, TransactionDate)...` and remove the group by and having clauses - this will let you see the individual records.  As you learn more, build your way back up to the query in the answer above (you will perhaps modify it along the way, depending on what you discover).